# Boostrap Toggle Navigation bar not working

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

I have written the following code but I can't get a toggle navbar. When I click on the button it doesn't collapse. I don't know why it's not working.
It might an error of my browser. But I don't think that so.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">tindog</a>

      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01"
        aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Download</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work. To help people answer your question, please check if you can get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TinDog</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <br>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

If you don't mention the scripts order properly your navbar won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in the console error, Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery.

So include this in the `head` and it will work just fine

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`